# How to Make CustomTabBar a setIsAccessibilityElement:YES

Tags: objective-c, ios, mobile

I have a CustomTabBar (.m) in my iOS app and cannot get setIsAccessibilityElement:YES Label/Hint to work.

I am accessing the button element via:
(UIButton*)[contentView viewWithTag:xxx];
and also trying to se it's accessibility options that way without success.

What should I look out for / do to make this work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the line `[self setIsAccessibilityElement: YES];` in CustomTabBar.m if it is of subclass UITabBarController and not UIViewController would solve the first problem.

Not able to get what you want to do in the second line. Would require further clarification.

Comment: Still no go :(.. My tabs are basically speaking "Tab 1 of 3" etc.. vs actually what their assigned label/hint. Maybe I am not assigning the tab's accessibility label/hint properly? Where should that go? Currently I have it in -(void)setButtonMain along their backgroundImage assignments (which work).

Comment: can you add some code and screenshots on what you are getting.. and which file(code) you want to access the button element?